# Use JQuery Date picker to select sundays

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need a help to create date picker for my webpage. I am using JSP (Jquery template). How can i implement date picker , it select only Sunday. After selecting the sunday i need to add 7 days to it, show i need to show in next text box 7th date. Is this possible to create?

My current code in script:

```
<script>
  function onSelDate()
  {
    var day1 = $("#DOB").datepicker('getDate').getDate();                 
    var month1 = $("#DOB").datepicker('getDate').getMonth();             
    var year1 = $("#DOB").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
    var fullDate = year1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + day1;                         
    var myDate=new Date();     
    myDate.setFullYear(year1,month1,day1);       
   }
   $(function() {
     $( "#DOB" ).datepicker();
   });
</script>
```

In input box:

```
<input type="text" name="bdate" onChange="onSelDate()" value=""id="DOB" style="width:70px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" size="20">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js">/script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#DOB").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonText: "select" });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks and Regards
Guru Bhat

![Now I can select any date, i need to select only sundays][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eORQ8.jpg

Comment: Does that mean, you want the user to select only Sunday from the calendar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("#datepickerID").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     minDate: 1,
     beforeShowDay: enableSUNDAYS
});
```